# Issue with JavaScript-based countdown clock

Tags: javascript, jquery, benchmarking

I'm trying to make a JavaScript countdown clock that starts from  1 hour all the way down.
I'm using just a bit of jQuery in the process.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var h,m,s,output;
$("#StartW").click(function(){
function startWork()
{
    h = 1;
    m = 0;
    s = 0;
    output = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    setInterval(function() {count()}, 1000);
}

function count()
{
    if(s == 0)
    {
        if(m == 0)
        {
            if(h == 0);
            {
                output = "time's up";
            }
            h = 0;
            m = 59;
            s = 59;
        }
    m = m - 1;
    s = 59;
    }
s = s - 1;
output = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
document.getElementById("WTM").innerHTML = output;
}
});
});
```

1- StartW is the id of the button calling the function.
2- WMT is the id of the span where the clock will be displayed.

When I click the button, I get no results. Nothing happens. The JavaScript Console in my navigator doesn't indicate any errors at all.

Comment: It appears to me that you are only defining your functions, but your aren't calling them. For instance, `startWork` is never called. May I also suggest you to define your functions outside the `click` handler?

Comment: example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZG3wx/ You should also read: http://goo.gl/NhxY90 A simple javascript countdown function.

Comment: thanks for lending me a hand guys :D

Answer (score 1):

In your click event function, you declare two functions, but never call them, so nothing happens. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var h,m,s,output;
    $("#StartW").click(function(){
        function startWork()
        {
            h = 1;
            m = 0;
            s = 0;
            output = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            setInterval(function() {count()}, 1000);
        }

        function count()
        {
            if(s == 0)
            {
                if(m == 0)
                {
                    if(h == 0)
                    {
                        output = "time's up";
                    }
                    h = 0;
                    m = 59;
                    s = 59;
                }
                m = m - 1;
                s = 59;
            }
            s = s - 1;
            output = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            document.getElementById("WTM").innerHTML = output;
        }
        startWork();
    });
});
```

Fixing indentation made it super clear, also there is a `;` on the line `if(h == 0);` that should be removed

As a note for your way to count one hour, you need to understand that it might not be very accurate. You ask the code to wait for 1000 milliseconds to add 1 second yourself, exactly like we do to count seconds saying "mississipi" to help us wait for the next second. Although JavaScript is more precise at counting 1000Milliseconds in 1 sec as we are to say mississipi in exactly one second, it might be off for X and Y reasons. The only real accurate way to know how long has elapsed is to watch the clock, and look at it again and again until it shows that we waited an hour. So, in JS, save the time when it started, every second or so display the remaining time by the difference of the current time and started time and display the timer.

Comment: You could also inform the OP that it's a bad practice to define his functions inside the event handler...

Comment: But you already did twice, and might not always be a bad idea IMO

Comment: Thanks, I really thought about it and you what you said is quite true. I'm thinking about using a date object which obtains its value from the UTC instead so that I could make sure that the time is more accurate :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, at pressing that button you don't call any function, you just initiate them. Get outside from click event the functions `count` and `startWork`, and do stuff like

`$('#StartW').on( 'click', startWork );`

Check it [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/288uj/)